# Different results from FFTW with FFTW_ESTIMATE and FFTW_MEASURE

Tags: c++, fft, precision, floating-accuracy, fftw

I'm using FFTW to perform FFTs on 2D image data. One can use either FFTW_ESTIMATE or FFTW_MEASURE to plan the FFT. I was assuming I get the same results when using either one. However I found a case where I get huge differences.

Code is (minimum example):

```
template<class T_IMG>
void aa(T_IMG& img)
{
    float* in = new float[2048*2048];
    float* in2 = new float[2048*2048];
    float* out = new float[2048*2048*2];
    float* out2 = new float[2048*2048*2];
    int dim[2] = {2048,2048};

    fftwf_plan plan1 = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c(2, dim, in, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(out), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftwf_plan plan2 = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c(2, dim, in2, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(out2), FFTW_MEASURE);
    img.load();
    for(int y=0; y<2048; y++)
        for(int x=0; x<2048; x++){
            in2[y*2048 + x] = img(x, y);//(std::abs(1024-x) < 20 && std::abs(1024-y) < 20) ? 1e9 : 0;
            in[y*2048 + x] = img(x, y); //(std::abs(1024-x) < 20 && std::abs(1024-y) < 20) ? 1e9 : 0;
        }
    fftwf_execute(plan2);
    fftwf_execute(plan1);
    for(int y=0; y<2048; y++)
        for(int x=0; x<1025; x++){
            float r1 = out[(y*1025 + x)*2];
            float r2 = out2[(y*1025 + x)*2];
            float c1 = out[(y*1025 + x)*2+1];
            float c2 = out2[(y*1025 + x)*2+1];
            float diffR = std::abs(r1-r2);
            float diffC = std::abs(c1-c2);
            if((diffR > 1 && diffR/std::abs(r1) > 1) || (diffC > 1 && diffC/std::abs(c1)) > 1){
                std::cerr << "Err " << diffR << "; " << diffC << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

I have an image with float values ranging from 0 to ~3e9. With a kind of sinc function in the middle. The error gets always triggered for example for (18, 229) vs (200, 466) on point (42, 91).

How is it possible, that those values are that far off? How can I solve that?

Additionally I tried to do the same in double precision. That worked... But I often cannot afford the overhead of the double precision calculations and expected to get reasonable values also for single precision.

Values at that point in DP are (-580, -166)

Comment: 52 bits =~ 4e15, while 23 bits =~ 8e6.  The 3e9 element will stomp all over your lower precision elements in a float: any value less than 400-ish will be noise, and even 400 will be reduced to contributing a single bit to the sum.  Meanwhile, 4e15 gives you 1.25e6 headroom -- you can add 1.0001 to 3e9 and get a different value than adding 1.0.  Basically, your range of values is far to large to do all math in single precision?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clFFT) is a google-hit OpenCL FFT that supports double precision on the Apache license.  Why use a handful of CPUs when you can use 1000s of GPUs?

Comment: I'm developing a library independent FFT interface in C++. So this is only one step of that ;)
BTW: OpenCL is Single GPU. So at most its 1000s of GPU cores.

Besides that: Pretty good explanation on bit sizes. Should be an answer to accept it. Do you know any way to decide, when to use DP over SP via an algorithm?

Comment: I can use two GPUs using OpenCL -- heck, I can get OpenCL to send jobs to the CPU and two GPUs.  They do have to be ... "separable? in some sense?" ... tasks, I'll admit.  And I'm not posting an answer, because I haven't done FFT or FFTW for any real problem, I just did back-of-napkin math on the magnitudes involved.

Comment: Sure and I can use MPI to use FFTW on 10000s of CPUs ;) Still stuff that is not there automaticly